# php email validation function does not get processed

Tags: php, html

I've written some code to create a contact form, however I have attempted to validate the email field and when I test using dummy data with incorrect email the function I use (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) does not get processed. I've added all my php and html code together in one file for easier readability and not to complicate things.

Here is my full code:

```
<?php 

// define variables and set to empty values
$first_nameErr = $last_nameErr = $emailErr = $messageErr  = "";
$first_name = $last_name = $email = $from = "";

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    $to = "pdgcaracas@gmail.com"; // this is your Email address
    // this is the sender's Email address
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $from = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = "Form submission";
    $subject2 = "Copy of your form submission";
    $message = $first_name . " " . $last_name . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
    $message2 = "Here is a copy of your message " . $first_name . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $headers2 = "From:" . $to;

    if (empty($_POST["first_name"])){
        $first_nameErr = " First name is required";
    }
    else if ((!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z-' ]*$/",$first_name))) {
        $first_nameErr = "Please type in only letters and whitespace";
    }
    else if(empty($_POST["last_name"])){
        $last_nameErr = " Last name is required";
    }
    else if ((!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z-' ]*$/",$last_name))) {
        $last_nameErr = "Please type in only letters and whitespace";
    }
    else if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $emailErr = "Email is required";
    }
    else if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { 
        $emailErr = "Email is invalid";
    }
    else if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
        $messageErr = "message is required";
    }
    else {
        mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
        mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender
        echo '<script>alert("Mail Sent. Thank you , we will contact you shortly.")</script>';
    }
    // You can also use header('Location: thank_you.php'); to redirect to another page.
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--
    Industrious by TEMPLATED
    templated.co @templatedco
    Released for free under the Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 license (templated.co/license)
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Generic Page - Industrious by TEMPLATED</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
    </head>
    <body class="is-preload">

        <!-- Header -->
            <header id="header">
                <a class="logo" href="index.html">Test</a>
                <nav>
                    <a href="#menu">Menu</a>
                </nav>
            </header>

        <!-- Nav -->
            <nav id="menu">
                <ul class="links">
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="elements.html">Elements</a></li>
                    <li><a href="aboutme.html">About me</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

        <!-- Heading -->
            <div id="heading" >
                <h1>Contact Us</h1>
            </div>

        <!-- Main -->
            <section id="main" class="wrapper">
                <div class="inner">
                    <div class="content">
                     <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name">
<span class="error">* <?php echo $first_nameErr;?></span>
<br>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name">
<span class="error">* <?php echo $last_nameErr;?></span><br>
Email: <input type="text" name="email">
<span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span><br>
Message:<br><textarea rows="5" name="message" cols="30"></textarea>
<span class="error">* <?php echo $messageErr;?></span><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">



  

  </form>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <!-- Footer -->
            <footer id="footer">
                <div class="inner">
                    <div class="content">
                        <section>
                            <h3>Accumsan montes viverra</h3>
                            <p>Nunc lacinia ante nunc ac lobortis. Interdum adipiscing gravida odio porttitor sem non mi integer non faucibus ornare mi ut ante amet placerat aliquet. Volutpat eu sed ante lacinia sapien lorem accumsan varius montes viverra nibh in adipiscing. Lorem ipsum dolor vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus vestibulum. Blandit adipiscing eu felis iaculis volutpat ac adipiscing sed feugiat eu faucibus. Integer ac sed amet praesent. Nunc lacinia ante nunc ac gravida.</p>
                        </section>
                        <section>
                            <h4>Sem turpis amet semper</h4>
                            <ul class="alt">
                                <li><a href="#">Dolor pulvinar sed etiam.</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Etiam vel lorem sed amet.</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Felis enim feugiat viverra.</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Dolor pulvinar magna etiam.</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </section>
                    <section>
                            <h4>Magna sed ipsum</h4>
                            <ul class="plain">
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon fa-twitter">&nbsp;</i>Twitter</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon fa-facebook">&nbsp;</i>Facebook</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon fa-instagram">&nbsp;</i>Instagram</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon fa-github">&nbsp;</i>Github</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </section>
                    </div>
                    <div class="copyright">
                        &copy; Untitled. Photos <a href="https://unsplash.co">Unsplash</a>, Video <a href="https://coverr.co">Coverr</a>.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </footer>

        <!-- Scripts -->
            <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/js/browser.min.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/js/breakpoints.min.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/js/util.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: You assign `$from = $_POST['email'];` but then you validate `$email` instead of `$from`.

Comment: Great! thanks for the feedback i don't know how I missed that!

Comment: Do you see anything else I may have missed in my code I went ahead and changed `else if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))` to `else if (filter_var($from, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))` but it is still not validating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

filter_var returns true only if the provided $email is valid.
To check if the email is invalid, change the if statement of filter_var as following and it should work

```
//your code
if (!(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))) { 
    $emailErr = "Email is invalid";
}
//your code
```